# Variables de Sesión

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Estoy trabajando con GeneXus 15 + JAVA Web y estoy usando variables de sesión (tipo de datos `WebSession`), para poder restringir el acceso a mi aplicación a menos que estén "logueados".

El problema es que no sé cada cuanto tiempo la variable de sesión se destruye por inactividad, y lo que quería saber es que si se puede controlar esa destrucción de variable,  de tal manera que cuando mi variable se destruya, me mande una pantalla que diga, “SU SESIÓN HA CADUCADO” o algo así.

Answer (score 2):

La sesión en el Tomcat, por defecto se vence cada 20/30 minutos.
Eso significa que cada ese tiempo, se perderá todo lo almacenado en la webSession.

Cuando la sesión expira, GX se comporta de acuerdo al valor de la propiedad ["OnSession Timeout"](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17458,On%20session%20timeout%20property)

> - **Ignore**  When the WebSession expires, the application will execute a refresh of the page in order to get a new WebSession and will not display any message. This is the default value.
> - **Warn**  When the WebSession expires or if it is invalid, a warning message will be displayed suggesting the user to refresh the page to get a new WebSession.

Comment: he visto información sobre GAMSession, creo que con eso funciona el OnSession Timeout, pero no puedo definir variables de tipo GAM, tengo que instalar un userControl o algo parecido?